# Python3 script consumes too much CPU

Tags: python-3.x, performance, memory

I have a simple script that subtract the first number from the list `het` with all the number from the list `het_noHet`, then it subtract the second number from the list `het` with all the number from the list `het_noHet` and so on:

Then, for each subtraction between both lists, it keeps the minimum number > 0:
formula : `d[i] = min(w[w>0])`

The script that I wrote is :

```
het = [12,40,50]
het_noHet = [5, 12, 22, 30, 40, 70]
import csv
def extraction_csv(csv_file):

        file_csv = []
        with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
                for rows in reader:

                        file_csv.append(''.join(rows))

        return (file_csv)

het = extraction_csv("het.csv")

het_noHet = extraction_csv("het_nothet.csv")

dico = {}
for i in het_noHet:
        for y in het:
                if abs(int(y)-int(i)) > 0:
                        if i not in dico.keys():
                                dico[i]=[(abs(int(y)-int(i)))]
                        elif isinstance(dico[i], list):
                                dico[i].append(abs(int(y)-int(i)))
                        else:
                                dico[i]= [dico[i],(abs(int(y)-int(i)))]


test = [min(x) for x in dico.values()]
print (test)
[7, 28, 10, 10, 10, 20]
```

The result is correct. However, normally het = 171K numbers and het_noHet = 530K numbers.

I am allowing the maximum memory per CPU that I can (32) but I keep getting the error message `/var/spool/slurmd/job7755164/slurm_script: line 16: 216342 Killed slurmstepd: error: Exceeded step memory limit at some point.`

I was wondering if someone has an idea to improve the script to use less memory?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How is `dico[i]` ever NOT a list? It starts as a list and it remains as a list when you call `append` on it.

Comment: I am really sorry but iam not sure to get what you meant

Comment: I think the test `elif isinstance(dico[i], list)` is always true. The statement `dico[i]= [dico[i],(abs(int(y)-int(i)))]` seems unreachable.

Comment: I used the elif to append the values associated to the same key. I agree for the statement (else)! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Exceeded step memory limit` is not so much a CPU problem as it is a memory problem.

It seems to me that `dico` has as many values as there are in `het_noHet`, and that each value in `dico` corresponds exactly to one entry in `het_noHet`. Hence, you calculate 530K lists of 171K items.

This means you need memory for all these lists, because you delay calling `min(x)` to the very end. Don't do that. Process one entry in `het_noHet` at a time, calculate one list of 171K items, call `min` on that list, and append one item to `test`. Then repeat this loop 530K times.

This reduces your memory by about 99.9995%.

For performance, using Numpy could keep `het` and `het_noHet` in much smaller memory allocations. Assuming `int32`, `het` would become about 700kB, well in range of the L3 cache on your CPU and possibly even L2. (`het_noHet` won't need cache since it's processed one item at a time, and that one item will be in a CPU register.)